# Generate a one-way path in 2d grid

Tags: algorithm, lua

I need a solution to a problem. I want to randomly generate path in a 3x3 grid in Lua. The path must be one way and not crossing the same point twice.

**The Grid:**

[image]

**The Code:**

```
math.randomseed( os.time())

moves={ {2,4},{1,5,3},{6,2},{1,5,7},{2,6,8,4},{3,5,9},{4,8},{7,5,9},{8,6} }

history_moves={}

last=0
start=1
print("first move: "..start)
table.insert(history_moves,start)

for a=1,6 do
  if a==1 then
    which_element=moves[start][ math.random(1,#moves[start]) ]
    print(which_element)
    last=which_element
    table.insert(history_moves,which_element)
  else 

    which_table=moves[which_element]
    which_element=which_table[ math.random(1,#which_table) ]
    print(which_element)
    last=which_element
    table.insert(history_moves,which_element)

  end
end
```

Table `moves` contains the possible direction of each point(`moves[1]` is for point 1, etc..)

The above snippet will generate a path, starting from point **1** and create the following:

```
 1 4 7 4 7 8 5
```

which is translated to this:

[image]

The problem is that the path going in used directions, that is points `4` and `7`

I have tried to include past point to `history_moves` but i cant figure how to utilize it.

The desired result would be for example:

```
1 4 7 8 5 6 9
```

Any help or ideas? I maybe reinventing the wheel here, but my algorithms knowledge is limited.

Comment: What path length is possible?  For example, 1-2-5-6-3 can't be continued.

Comment: Did think of that to be honest, maybe until it can't be continued.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all the used points in an array, `usedPoints`, and check against that array when you choose a new point.

If the chosen point is already in the `usedPoints` array, choose another point, otherwise, choose that point and add it to `usedPoints`.